# Why does Eclipse turn a maven runtime dependency into a compile dependency?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a maven project imported into Eclipse Oxygen.  Eclipse reports no compile issues (`Alt + F5`).  When I run maven from the command line I get

```
[ERROR] /home/dean/src/TAP3UIs/TAP3Desktop/src/main/java/com/ms/tap3/controller/RequestAccessController.java:[8,30] package com.google.common.base does not exist
```

That package does exist in my .m2/repository in guava-15.0.jar.  I can also see it in Eclipse mvn dependencies.  When I check the `mvn dependency:tree` for the project I see

`[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0:runtime`

It is a runtime transitive dependency on the command line, which explains why it doesn't compile on the command line.  Somehow Eclipse has turned a transitive dependency from runtime to compile.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I make Eclispe m2e respect the scope of the transitive dependencies?

Comment: Is there any non-maven library within the Eclipse project's Java Build Path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, neither [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) nor [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) support multiple classpaths per project which is required to support different scopes.

See: [Eclipse bug 486035 - Different classpath containers for different scopes](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486035)

**Update**:

**Since Eclipse Photon (4.8)** which was released in June 2018 this is **now supported**. See [Eclipse bug 526858](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526858) and [my video showing this in action](https://youtu.be/U-ZTkhek5TU?t=218).

Comment: Interesting. How does m2e "interpret" scopes then? Does it include compile,runtime,provided, but ignores test?

Comment: @JFMeier One classpath that contains everything, e. g. with the dependency `junit` of the scope `test` JUnit is also visible in `src/main/java`. Surprisingly, most users don't seem to notice this.

Comment: Are any of the other IDEs (NetBeans, IntelliJ) better at supporting different maven scopes?

Comment: @DeanSchulze Other IDEs just run regular Maven builds. IntelliJ, for example, compiles the code before running/debugging it with the disadvantage of a considerable delay before _Run/Debug_, but I guess code completion takes scopes into account. In Eclipse you should run a Maven build from time to time or use a continuous integration server for that. You could also use a separate project for the test code in Eclipse.

Comment: @DeanSchulze Yes.  In my opinion IntelliJ supports Maven much better than Eclipse m2e (especially with Auto-Import active).  I have not spent much time with Netbeans, but it is my understanding that Maven is very well supported there too.  Unfortunately Netbeans has lost a lot of momentum after Oracle handed it over to Apache, and there has not been an official release supporting Java 9 yet.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen In Eclipse, the classpath is used by the incremental compiler which compiles on save by default. If you click on _Run_ or _Debug_, the application starts immediately and hot code replace works as expected. Of course, m2e also supports to run a regular Maven build (it does not _"emulate"_ Maven, but just runs the embedded or a local installed Maven). In my opinion, however, this should not be done by the developer, but by a continuous integration server. I prefer not to have the support of scopes rather than being slowed down.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Believe it or don't believe it, if you run a Maven build (Alt+Shift+X, M) with test code in `src/main/java`, you get a `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ...` error in Eclipse.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen 1) Create a new Maven project or open a project that contains a `pom.xml` file. 2) Hit Alt+Shift+X, M. Calling 2) _"deliberately and explicitly branch out to Maven"_ is precisely the point here.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen m2e runs by default the embedded Maven (you do not need to have Maven installed). Your claim was _"The Eclipse support of Maven is an incomplete emulation which mostly works"_, you did not mention scopes. By default, Eclipse uses its own incremental compiler on saving without emulating Maven. If you want to compile with Maven, just hit Alt+Shift+X, M to override the compiled classes. This runs always the embedded Maven, not only mostly without emulating something. Do we agree that your statement is false?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Why did you delete my comment?

Comment: @howlger Sorry, your conclusion is incorrect.  I did an invisible edit to be able to retract my upvote.  Before you jump to another conclusion, please note I did not downvote instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I already noticed you withdrew your upvote without comment. That is not what I asked. I feel very uncomfortable that my answer has been hijacked by your comments. To say _"The Eclipse support of Maven is an incomplete emulation which mostly works"_ is at least misleading because it implies that Maven builds would fail sporadically in Eclipse. Without being able to say what is emulated and what is 100%, it is not a technical but an opinion-based statement.

Answer (score 2):

The main point is this: If you import external classes in your source code, you must set them as **compile** dependencies, and never trust the fact that they *might* already be transitive dependencies (because, since they are transitive, you have not direct control over them, so in a future version they might diseappear as well).

What is happening is this:

- You need some classes from com.google.common.base package, so you need to set `com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0` as a dependency.
- Instead, you didn't because you realised it was already a transitive dependency, but you missed the fact that is a *runtime* dependency.
- Eclipse M2 does not distinguish the different Maven's standard classpaths, so it treats all dependencies as if they were of "compile" scope. So Eclipse includes `guava-15.0.jar` in the compilation and the project is compiled OK.
- Maven, instead, won't include a *runtime* dependency in the compilation phase, so a compile error is raised.

In brief: You should include `guava-15.0` (as well as any other artifact your code needs) as a **direct dependency** (with **compile** scope) in your pom file.

Comment: Downvoting is OK, but a little comment won't harm me either.